# Characterization of positive elements in unital C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital C*-algebra (not necessarily commutative) and let $A^*=A\in \mathcal{A}$ be a self-adjoint element with $\vert\vert A \vert\vert \leq 2$?

I want to show that $\vert\vert \mathbb{1}-A \vert\vert \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow \sigma(A)\subset [0,\infty)$ (i.e. $A$ is positive), but don't really see the connection.

How can approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal A$ be the sub-$C^*$-algebra generated by $1$ and $A.$ Then $\mathcal B$ is commutative, so $\mathcal B\simeq C(X).$ Let $f_A\in C(X)$ be the function corresponding to $A.$ The following implications hold:
\begin{gather*}
||1-A||\leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow ||1-f_A||_\infty\leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow |1-f_A|\leq 1\ \mbox{on}\ X\\ \Longleftrightarrow 0\leq f_A\leq 2\ \mbox{on}\ X\Longleftrightarrow 0\leq A\leq 2\ (\mbox{in } \mathcal B)\Longleftrightarrow 0\leq A\leq 2\ (\mbox{in } \mathcal A)
\end{gather*}
(Here $||\cdot||_\infty$ is the supremum norm on $X,$ i.e. norm in $C(X)$)

It solves your problem.

Comment: I think you missed two norms in the last two steps. If you put an order relation on positive elements, you should define and clarify it, because it might confuse the OP.

Comment: @Marc Palm: If madison54 knows about positive elements, I believe he knows about order relation on self-adjoint elements.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: Can I always take the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ for your compact Hausdorff space $X$?

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: I'm confused by your notation. Does $0\leq A \leq 2$ mean that $A$ and $(2\mathbb{1}-A)$ are positive elements in $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: @madison54: Yes, one can show that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\sigma(A).$

Comment: @madison54: $0\leq A\leq 2$ means that $A$ and $2-A$ are positive. Note, that the last implication uses the fact that positivity w.r.t. $\mathcal A$ is equivalent to positivity w.r.t. $\mathcal B.$ Equivalently, $\sigma_{\mathcal A}(\cdot)=\sigma_{\mathcal B}(\cdot).$

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: Another question: why does $0\leq f_A \leq 2 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq A \leq 2$ hold? If you take $X=\sigma(A)$, then there can be negative $x\in X$ but $f_A(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: @madison54: $0\leq f_A\leq 2\Longleftrightarrow 0\leq A\leq 2\ (\mbox{in } \mathcal B)$ holds because $\mathcal B$ and $C(X)$ are isomorphic.